# Printing a board in Commodore Basic 4.0?

Tags: basic, commodore

I'm having trouble with printing a board of dots in Commodore Basic 6502.

This is what I have to far: (it's a subroutine)

```
10 INPUT "Please enter a number:", X
20 DIM A$(X, X)
30 FOR I = 0 TO X
40 FOR J = 0 TO X
50 A$(I, J) = "."
60 NEXT
70 NEXT
80 PRINT A$
END
```

Can anyone help me out with it because when I paste it into the emulator, type END, and press enter literally nothing happens?

Any help is much appreciated. I'm trying to build a word search game.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question *simply* because it's so old school.

Comment: Also, gonna take a wild guess that you can't *print* an array.  You probably have to print each element within the array.

Comment: Is this a real machine?  Pet, Vic-20, C-64?  Or a simulator?

Comment: You need to type `RUN` and hit enter to get it to go.  There are also some other problems as folks have noted, and, from deepest darkest corners of my memory, I think arrays are 1-based, not 0-based.

Comment: why on earth was this downvoted? Just getting this far is plus worthy enough. Curious as to why you would be programming it at all

Comment: OK, so it appears I was wrong about the 1-based arrays :)

Comment: this is an emulator; C-64 with basic 4.0

Comment: @Suraya if you are talking about Basic 4.0 this machine must be one of the PET/CMB models. C64 was shipped with Basic 2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for laughs, here is some code that does what I think you want to do:

[image: C64 screen shot]

Just type `RUN` and hit enter!

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did you type in the code as well?

Comment: Got it; for some reason I had to put everything in lowercase...odd. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Snip to fill an array with dots and print it:

```
10 INPUT "Please enter a number:", X
20 DIM A$(X, X)
21 REM make the array
30 FOR I = 0 TO X
    40 FOR J = 0 TO X
        50 A$(I, J) = "."
    60 NEXT
70 NEXT
80 REM print the array
90 FOR I = 0 TO X
    91 FOR J = 0 TO X
        92 PRINT A$(I, J);
    93 NEXT
    94 PRINT
95 NEXT
99 END
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to instantiate the array A$:

```
10 rows=12
20 cols=10
30 gosub 1000
40 end
50 :
1000 for i=1 to rows
1010   for j=1 to cols
1020     print ".";
1030   next
1040   print
1060 next

run
```